# Writing a test class for an HttpPost

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, httppost

I'm not able to figure out how to get any code coverage on an Apex HttpPost method.

Apex class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/approve/*')
global with sharing class exAppClass {
jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c ts = new jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c();
    // GET request
   @HttpPost
    global static String doGet() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;   
      String secid = req.params.get('id');
      String approverId = req.params.get('appid');
      String ipString = req.params.get('ip');
      System.debug(secid);
      String alreadyApproved = 'expired';
      String error = 'error';
      String success = 'approved';
      String primApprover;
      String secApprover;
      jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c ts;
      ts = [SELECT Id, jstcl__Week_Ending__c, jstcl__Status__c, jstcl__Placement__r.jstcl__SecondaryApprover__c, jstcl__Placement__r.jstcl__TimecardApprover__c FROM jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c WHERE Id = :tsid FOR UPDATE];
      primApprover = String.valueOf(ts.jstcl__Placement__r.jstcl__TimecardApprover__c);
      secApprover = String.valueOf(ts.jstcl__Placement__r.jstcl__SecondaryApprover__c);  
      if (ts != null && ts.jstcl__Status__c == 'Approved' && (primApprover == approverId || secApprover == approverId )) {
        return alreadyApproved;
      } else if(ts != null && ts.jstcl__Status__c == 'Submitted' && (primApprover == approverId || secApprover == approverId)){
        try{
            insertLog(ts, approverId, ipString);
            ts.jstcl__Status__c = 'Approved';
            update ts;   
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('Exception caught: ' + e.getMessage()); 
            return error;   
        } 
      return success;
      }else {
      return error;
      }
    }
 
    private static Express_Approval_Log__c insertLog(jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c ts, Id approverId, String ip){
      Express_Approval_Log__c log = new Express_Approval_Log__c();
      log.Name = 'EAL '+ts.jstcl__Week_Ending__c;
      log.Timesheet__c = ts.Id;
      log.Approval_Date_Time__c= DateTime.now();
      log.Status__c = 'Approved';
      log.Timesheet_Approver__c = approverId;
      log.IP_Address__c = ip;
     try{
        insert log;
     }catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug('Exception caught: ' + e.getMessage());    
    } 
      return log;
  }
}
```

Test Class (so far):

```
@isTest
private class exAppClassTest {
@isTest static void exAppClassUnitTest() {

Test.startTest();

Contact con = new Contact(
        FirstName='fname',
        LastName = 'lname',
        Email = 'email@gmail.com',
        Phone = '9743800309'); 
insert con; 
ts2__Placement__c plc = new ts2__Placement__c();
plc.jstcl__SecondaryApprover__c = con.Id;
plc.jstcl__TimecardApprover__c = con.Id;
insert plc;
jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c ts =new jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c ();
date mydate = date.parse('12/27/2009');
ts.jstcl__Status__c='Test';
ts.jstcl__Week_Ending__c=mydate ;
insert ts;
Express_Approval_Log__c log = new Express_Approval_Log__c();
log.Name = 'EAL '+ts.jstcl__Week_Ending__c;
log.Timesheet__c = ts.Id;
log.Approval_Date_Time__c= DateTime.now();
log.Status__c = 'Approved';
log.IP_Address__c = '12:12:123';
log.Timesheet_Approver__c = plc.jstcl__TimecardApprover__c;
    insert log;
RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/exAppClass/';  //Request URL
//req.requestBody = Blob.valueof(JsonMsg);
 req.httpMethod = 'POST';
RestContext.request = req;
RestContext.response= res;
exAppClass.doGet();
Test.stopTest();
}
}
```

Comment: If you haven't checked it out yet, I recommend doing [Trailhead's tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts) on this. They go over testing as well.

Comment: @Tim Hunter - All examples I've come across have an apex class returning an HttpResponse however I am returning a String in this instance. I'm unsure how to test for a POST method that is returning a String.

Comment: @LukeHiggins That's not how you use HttpPost requests. You would put the String into the Body of the HttpResponse object if that's the content you want returned.